# jQuery if condition for radio button name and value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio button like

```
<input type="radio" name="user-type" value="Store">
<input type="radio" name="user-type" value="Brand">
```

I tried writing jQuery script like

```
if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val()) == "Brand"){
     $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
}
```

and also tried

```
if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val()) == "Brand").click(function(){
       $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
});
```

and also tried

```
if ( $("input[name=user-type]:radio").val() == "Brand"){
     $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
}
```

None of these worked, any correction is appreciated. Thanks.

**Update1**

I tried in this way and this hide both

```
if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val() == "Brand"){
     $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
}
else if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val() == "Store"){
     $(".showstore").show();
     $(".showbrand").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following code - it basically listens for `click` on radio `name=user-type`, and toggles based on which radio button was clicked.

```
$(function () {
    $('.showstore').hide();
    $('.showbrand').hide();

    $("input[name=user-type]:radio").click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=user-type]:checked').val() == "Brand") {
            $('.showstore').hide();
            $('.showbrand').show();

        } else if ($('input[name=user-type]:checked').val() == "Store") {
            $('.showstore').show();
            $('.showbrand').hide();

        }
    });
});
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FpUSH/1/

Answer (score 7):

This is short

```
$('input:radio').change(
function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Store'){
        $('.showbrand').hide();
        $('.showstore').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.showstore').hide();
        $('.showbrand').show();
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Karthik Malla

Answer (score 2):

You have one syntax error, You have closed the `parenthesis` belongs to the if statement wrongly

```
if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val() == "Brand"){
     $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/hNAcL/)

```
$("input[name=user-type]").change(function(){
  $(".showstore").toggle(this.value === "Store"); 
  $(".showbrand").toggle(this.value === "Brand"); 
});
```

### [NEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/73wKE/1/)

Comment: I tried this way and its hiding both on clicking.

if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val() == "Brand"){
     $(".showstore").hide();
     $(".showbrand").show();
}
else if($("input[name=user-type]:checked").val() == "Store"){
     $(".showstore").show();
     $(".showbrand").hide();
}

Comment: That should work all time, each time the option is changed it should show/hide.

Comment: @lock The code that you have accepted just now looks like the face of the answerer... Eeek.. Isn't it? have a look at my code.. And by the way you are having free rights to change your acceptance at anytime... :)

Answer (score 2):

there are just some syntax errors:

```
$("input[name='user-type']:checked").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Brand"){
        $(".showstore").hide();
        $(".showbrand").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check like this:

```
if($('input[name="user-type"]:checked').val() === "Brand")
{
       alert("Test");
       // do something here
}
```

[**Working Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/tG7yM/)

Answer (score 1):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/tG7yM/) try this,

```
if(jQuery("input:radio[name='user-type']:checked").val()=="Brand"){
   //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely @karthikr has a good and functional approach.

Here it's one example for Yes/No radio-buttons in case you want to disable an element depending if the radio-button selection

```
$("input[name=button-name]:radio").click(function () {
    if ($('input[name=input-radio-name]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
        $( "element" ).removeClass('btn-display-none');
        $( "element" ).prop('disabled', false);

    } else {
        $( "element" ).addClass('btn-display-none'));
        $( "element" ).prop('disabled', true);

    }
});
```

Source: Used for a own project